# SQL query to print the top 10 highest calculated amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been writing a query to find the total sale amount for each order and return the top 10 highest amounts with ties. So, i wrote this query

```
select OrderID,
       SUM((UnitPrice-Discount/100)*quantity) as TotalSale,
       dense_rank() over(order by TotalSale desc) as rnk
from dbo.[Order Details]
where rnk <= 10   
GROUP BY ORDERID
ORDER BY TotalSale DESC
```

So, when i run this i get error saying rnk and totalsale are invalid columns.  The query returns the value if i remove dense_rank(). Can u please help me in solving the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference windowing functions in the same query, you need to provide a sub-query.  You also cannot reference `TotalSale` by alias, you must use the calculation again.

```
WITH ranked AS
(
   SELECT OrderID
      , SUM( (UnitPrice - Discount / 100) * quantity) AS TotalSale
      , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY SUM( (UnitPrice - Discount / 100) * quantity) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM dbo.[Order Details]
)
SELECT OrderID, TotalSale
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk <= 10
GROUP BY OrderID
ORDER BY TotalSale DESC
```

Comment: invalid column: total sale in the dense_rank

Comment: I've updated the query to reference the calculation, not the alias.

Answer (score 1):

TotalSale does not exist in the context of the OVER() function. Try this:

```
select * from (
select
   OrderID,
   SUM((UnitPrice-Discount/100)*quantity) as TotalSale,
   dense_rank() over(order by SUM((UnitPrice-Discount/100)*quantity) desc) as rnk
from dbo.[Order Details]) oDetails
where rnk <= 10   
GROUP BY ORDERID
ORDER BY TotalSale DESC
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. You also need to provide the full definition of rnk in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses is the error i'm getting

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of rnk and use the top clause.

Comment: i have some ties. So, i need to display top 10 highest including ties

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the 'TOP 10' keywords instead of using a rank?

```
SELECT TOP 10 ORDERID, SUM((UnitPrice-Discount/100)*quantity) as TotalSale
FROM <table>
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOP 10 OrderID,SUM((UnitPrice-Discount/100)*quantity) as TotalSale
from dbo.[Order Details] 
GROUP BY ORDERID
ORDER BY SUM((UnitPrice-Discount/100)*quantity) DESC
```

or

```
SELECT OrderID, TotalSale
FROM (
SELECT OrderID
      , SUM((UnitPrice-Discount/100)*quantity) AS TotalSale
      , dense_rank() over(order by TotalSale desc) AS rnk
   FROM dbo.[Order Details]
) AS X
WHERE rnk <= 10
GROUP BY OrderID
ORDER BY TotalSale DESC
```

Comment: i get invalid column name total sales .... i cant use first query because i have some ties and i need to display them

Answer (score 0):

```
    select    OrderId, sum((UnitPrice-Discount/100)*quantity) as TotalSale
    from      [Order Details] od join
    (
        select top 10 TotalSale from
        (
            select    distinct sum((UnitPrice-Discount/100)*quantity) as TotalSale
            from      [Order Details]
            group by  orderid
            order by  TotalSale desc
        ) sales
    ) topsales on od.TotalSale = topsales topsales.TotalSale

    group by  orderid
    order by  TotalSale desc
```

Basically, you need to find out what the top ten distinct amounts are first.  Then you can look for all amounts that match any of those top ten amounts.

Comment: yeah more than 10 results when there are ties

Comment: Okay, see if that works... I'm double checking for any mistakes I might have made but I think that's right.

Comment: I made one edit to move the distinct into the inner query.  It might have worked the way it was before, and you might even be able to merge the inner two queries to just have one inner query.  But this should work for sure.